# How to get clint IPv4 address by php

Tags: php, mysql

All day long I tried various method to get a real id of each client in same server. So I tried to get a ip as id.

I work with php and want to get register user ip in Mysql also for ip base voting system.

But I confused how to get IPv4 address for each client. Because
At first I tried to get my own ip for test.

At one of my laptop (at Broadband connection detail)I found:

```
Clint IPv4 address:  172.xx.xxx.333
Server IPv4 address: 172.xx.xxx.2

Whatismyipaddress.com show:  124.x.xxx.xx
My cPanel also show as same: 124.x.xxx.xx
```

And a another laptop in same network but different connection:

```
Clint IPv4 address:  172.xx.yy.444
Server IPv4 address: 172.xx.yy.2

Whatismyipaddress.com show:  124.x.xxx.xx
My cPanel also show as same: 124.x.xxx.xx
```

So I found IPv4 is different for each pc.

Now when I try to get IPv4 address, my every code display same internet ip as whatismyip.com?

Here all method in stackoverflow and google search give as same result as whatismyip.com.

I also cannot found any good or easy answer for this issue too.

Method 1:

```
function get_client_ip()
{
  $ipaddress = '';
  if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
  else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
  else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
  else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
  else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
  else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
  else
      $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

  return $ipaddress;
 }
 $ip = get_client_ip();
 echo $ip;
```

Method 2:

```
function get_ip_address() {
$ip_keys = array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR');
foreach ($ip_keys as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
        foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
            // trim for safety measures
            $ip = trim($ip);
            // attempt to validate IP
            if (validate_ip($ip)) {
                return $ip;
            }
        }
    }
}

return isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : false;
}

function validate_ip($ip)
{
if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) === false) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}

$ip = get_ip_address();
echo $ip;
```

Comment: You want to read about NAT. You are obviously inside a local network (the `172....` addresses are a reserved address space, non-routable in the internet). That local network is connected to the internet through NAT. For a server outside the local network all request indeed do come from the same IP address, the outside address of the NAT router. These are basic network topology things, you want to start reading about that.

Comment: Sorry for wrong word. edited. Thank u. I am reading. . .

Comment: BTW: this is also why an IP based session management rarely is a good starting point. Per definition it can only work in very specific situations like internal networks. And even there you might experience interesting surprises. For example several people might use a single system to send requests at the same time. You simply cannot rely on the assumption of a 1:1 relationsship between "a user" and an ip address.

Comment: Thank you sir. So have and others method to get a client address or information which publicly can I use? If you say NO; my voting system not work in same network.!!!

Comment: You did not understand what I explained, I think. Once more: an IP address is unsuitable for the task, no matter how you determine the address. It simply is not unique.

Comment: Thank you sir. I am now clear about network address system. I am reading more. . .

Comment: You are welcome! A hint: think about how other systems achieve what you are looking for. Take a look at php sessions for example.